# Python Pandas - Cannot Merge Multiple DataFrame returning NaN

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge multiple CSV files into that of 1 large dataframe. I want to merge them in respect to that of the Date Column. Although some CSV files have missing dates and will require a blank or NA to be recorded.

Searching around led me to believe that pandas in python would be a viable solution.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

AvgPrice = pd.read_csv('csv/BAVERAGE-USD-Bitcoin24hPrice.csv', index_col=False)
AvgPrice = AvgPrice.iloc[:,(0,1)]
AvgPrice.columns.values[1] = 'Price'

TransVol = pd.read_csv('csv/BCHAIN-ETRAV-BitcoinEstimatedTransactionVolume.csv', index_col=False)
TransVol.columns.values[1] = 'TransactionVolume'

TotalBTC = pd.read_csv('csv/BCHAIN-TOTBC-TotalBitcoins.csv', index_col=False)
TotalBTC.columns.values[1] = 'TotalBTC'

USDExchVol = pd.read_csv('csv/BCHAIN-TRVOU-BitcoinUSDExchangeTradeVolume.csv', index_col=False)
USDExchVol.columns.values[1] = 'USDExchange Volume'

df1 = pd.merge(TransVol, AvgPrice, on='Date', how='outer')
df2 = pd.merge(USDExchVol, TotalBTC, on='Date', how='outer)

df_test = pd.merge(AvgPrice, TransVol, on='Date', how='outer')
```

CSV files are located here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8xdmDmZgtJbVkhCcjZkZUhaajg&usp=sharing

Results of df_test:

```
            Date   Price  TransactionVolume
0     2016-05-10  459.30                NaN
1     2016-05-09  462.49                NaN
2     2016-05-08  461.85                NaN
3     2016-05-07  460.86                NaN
4     2016-05-06  453.51                NaN
5     2016-05-05  449.31                NaN
```

Whereas df1 seems to be fine:

```
            Date  TransactionVolume   Price
0     2016-05-10           275352.0  459.30
1     2016-05-09           256585.0  462.49
2     2016-05-08           152045.0  461.85
3     2016-05-07           245115.0  460.86
4     2016-05-06           264882.0  453.51
5     2016-05-05           273005.0  449.31
```

I have no idea why df2 and df_test have the right most column filled with NaN. This is restricting me from merging both df1 and df2 to make one large DataFrame.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've spent hours with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add parameters `names` and `usecols` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), and then it works nice:

```
import pandas as pd

AvgPrice = pd.read_csv('csv/BAVERAGE-USD-Bitcoin24hPrice.csv', 
                       index_col=False, 
                       parse_dates=['Date'],
                       usecols=[0,1],
                       header=0, 
                       names=['Date','Price'])

TransVol = pd.read_csv('csv/BCHAIN-ETRAV-BitcoinEstimatedTransactionVolume.csv', 
                       index_col=False, 
                       parse_dates=['Date'],
                       header=0, 
                       names=['Date','TransactionVolume'])


TotalBTC = pd.read_csv('csv/BCHAIN-TOTBC-TotalBitcoins.csv', 
                       index_col=False, 
                       parse_dates=['Date'],
                       header=0, 
                       names=['Date','TotalBTC'])


USDExchVol = pd.read_csv('csv/BCHAIN-TRVOU-BitcoinUSDExchangeTradeVolume.csv', 
                       index_col=False,
                       parse_dates=['Date'],
                       header=0, 
                       names=['Date','USDExchange Volume'])
```

```
df1 = pd.merge(TransVol, AvgPrice, on='Date', how='outer')
df2 = pd.merge(USDExchVol, TotalBTC, on='Date', how='outer')
df_test = pd.merge(AvgPrice, TransVol, on='Date', how='outer')

print (df1.head())
print (df2.head())
print (df_test.head())
        Date  TransactionVolume   Price
0 2016-05-10           275352.0  459.30
1 2016-05-09           256585.0  462.49
2 2016-05-08           152045.0  461.85
3 2016-05-07           245115.0  460.86
4 2016-05-06           264882.0  453.51
        Date  USDExchange Volume    TotalBTC
0 2016-05-10        2.158373e+06  15529625.0
1 2016-05-09        1.438420e+06  15525825.0
2 2016-05-08        6.679933e+05  15521275.0
3 2016-05-07        1.825475e+06  15517400.0
4 2016-05-06        1.908048e+06  15513525.0
        Date   Price  TransactionVolume
0 2016-05-10  459.30           275352.0
1 2016-05-09  462.49           256585.0
2 2016-05-08  461.85           152045.0
3 2016-05-07  460.86           245115.0
4 2016-05-06  453.51           264882.0
```

EDIT by comment:

I think you can convert column `Date` [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) of `months` and then use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
print (df1.Date.dt.to_period('M'))
0      2016-05
1      2016-05
2      2016-05
3      2016-05
4      2016-05
5      2016-05
6      2016-05
7      2016-05
...
...
print (df1.groupby( df1.Date.dt.to_period('M') ).mean() )
         TransactionVolume       Price
Date                                  
2011-05       1.605518e+05    7.272273
2011-06       1.739163e+05   17.914583
2011-07       6.647129e+04   14.100645
2011-08       1.050460e+05   10.089677
2011-09       9.562243e+04    5.933667
2011-10       9.120232e+04    3.638065
2011-11       8.927442e+05    2.690333
2011-12       1.092328e+06    3.463871
2012-01       1.168704e+05    6.105161
2012-02       1.465859e+05    5.115517
...
...
```

If order is important, add parameter `sort=False`:

```
print (df1.groupby( df1.Date.dt.to_period('M') , sort=False).mean() )
         TransactionVolume       Price
Date                                  
2016-05       2.511146e+05  454.544000
2016-04       2.747255e+05  435.102333
2016-03       3.142206e+05  418.208710
2016-02       3.402811e+05  404.091379
2016-01       2.548778e+05  412.671935
2015-12       3.857985e+05  423.402903
2015-11       4.290366e+05  349.200333
2015-10       3.134802e+05  266.007097
2015-09       2.572308e+05  235.310345
2015-08       2.737384e+05  253.951613
...
...
```

Comment: Beautiful thanks :)
Another thing off topic that I'm finding it hard is say I want to make a summary of df1 and find the average value in each month. How could I do so with say df1.groupby( TimeGrouper('1M') ) etc. I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be.

Comment: Do you think `year` and `month` together, right? Or average of all Januaries, Feb.. ?

Comment: Sweet exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so very much !

Comment: Interesting. Your solution `StackOverflow` take as accepted, but there is not `green` mark. See `11` row: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael?tab=reputation . Maybe bug. Do you accept it or not?

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle bug here, you're renaming the columns by directly assigning to the column array in each df:

```
AvgPrice.columns.values[1] = 'Price'
```

If you try `TransVol.info()` it raises a `KeyError` on `TransactionVolume`

if instead you use `rename` then it works:

```
In [35]:
AvgPrice = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\BAVERAGE-USD-Bitcoin24hPrice.csv', index_col=False)
AvgPrice = AvgPrice.iloc[:,(0,1)]
AvgPrice.rename(columns={'24h Average':'Price'}, inplace=True)
​
TransVol = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\BCHAIN-ETRAV-BitcoinEstimatedTransactionVolume.csv', index_col=False)
TransVol.rename(columns={'Value':'TransactionVolume'}, inplace=True)
​
TotalBTC = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\BCHAIN-TOTBC-TotalBitcoins.csv', index_col=False)
TotalBTC.rename(columns={'Value':'TotalBTC'}, inplace=True)
​
USDExchVol = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\BCHAIN-TRVOU-BitcoinUSDExchangeTradeVolume.csv', index_col=False)
USDExchVol.rename(columns={'Value':'USDExchange Volume'}, inplace=True)
​
df1 = pd.merge(TransVol, AvgPrice, on='Date', how='outer')
df2 = pd.merge(USDExchVol, TotalBTC, on='Date', how='outer')
​
df_test = pd.merge(AvgPrice, TransVol, on='Date', how='outer')
df_test
Out[35]:
            Date   Price  TransactionVolume
0     2016-05-10  459.30           275352.0
1     2016-05-09  462.49           256585.0
2     2016-05-08  461.85           152045.0
3     2016-05-07  460.86           245115.0
4     2016-05-06  453.51           264882.0
5     2016-05-05  449.31           273005.0
6     2016-05-04  449.32           370911.0
7     2016-05-03  447.93           252534.0
8     2016-05-02  448.00           249926.0
9     2016-05-01  452.87           170791.0
10    2016-04-30  454.88           190470.0
11    2016-04-29  451.88           278893.0
12    2016-04-28  445.80           329924.0
13    2016-04-27  461.92           335750.0
14    2016-04-26  465.91           344162.0
15    2016-04-25  460.32           307790.0
16    2016-04-24  455.53           188499.0
17    2016-04-23  449.13           203792.0
18    2016-04-22  447.73           291487.0
19    2016-04-21  445.28           316159.0
20    2016-04-20  438.98           302380.0
21    2016-04-19  432.35           275994.0
22    2016-04-18  429.76           245313.0
23    2016-04-17  431.93           186607.0
24    2016-04-16  432.86           200628.0
25    2016-04-15  429.06           281389.0
26    2016-04-14  426.21           274524.0
27    2016-04-13  425.50           309995.0
28    2016-04-12  426.15           341372.0
29    2016-04-11  422.91           264357.0
...          ...     ...                ...
1798  2011-05-18    7.14            80290.0
1799  2011-05-17    7.52           138205.0
1800  2011-05-16    7.77            62341.0
1801  2011-05-15    6.74           272130.0
1802  2011-05-14    7.86           656162.0
1803  2011-05-13    7.48           324020.0
1804  2011-05-12    5.83           101674.0
1805  2011-05-11    5.35           114243.0
1806  2011-05-10    4.74           104592.0
1807  2015-09-03     NaN           256023.0
1808  2015-02-03     NaN           213538.0
1809  2015-01-07     NaN           256344.0
1810  2014-11-21     NaN           161082.0
1811  2014-10-17     NaN           142251.0
1812  2014-09-28     NaN            92933.0
1813  2014-09-09     NaN           111317.0
1814  2014-08-05     NaN           136298.0
1815  2014-08-03     NaN            49181.0
1816  2014-08-01     NaN           166173.0
1817  2014-06-03     NaN           124768.0
1818  2014-06-02     NaN            87513.0
1819  2014-05-09     NaN            80315.0
1820  2013-10-27     NaN           107717.0
1821  2013-09-17     NaN           137920.0
1822  2011-06-25     NaN           110463.0
1823  2011-06-24     NaN           106146.0
1824  2011-06-23     NaN           475995.0
1825  2011-06-22     NaN           122507.0
1826  2011-06-21     NaN           114264.0
1827  2011-06-20     NaN           836861.0

[1828 rows x 3 columns]
```